# Запуск python в командной строке

Tags: python, windows, cmd

Добрый день, хочу, чтобы python, pip запускались прямо в cmd. Сейчас они открываются в новом окне.
Например, я хочу запустить Pip, но он открывается в окне на мгновение.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Думаю, стоит указать как именно вы запускаете python.

Answer (score 6):

Наверное вы просто не знакомы с интерфейсом командной строки.

Запуск производится в уже запущенном экземпляре командной строки, а не двойным кликом, как это скорее всего делаете вы. Передача аргументов производится посредством текстового ввода, а не в каком-то магическом окне.

Для начала запустите экземпляр командной строки, запустив, например `cmd` из окна запуска приложений (пуск-выполнить или `Win-R`). Далее уже там перейдите в нужную директорию (команда `cd`) и уже там выполните команду `pip`.